# Improve the quality of texture sample in Direct3D

Tags: textures, scale, render, direct3d

I'm using directx 11 to render video.I create a Texture2D and copy rgba video data into it.Also it is the resource of pixel shader.Here is code:

```
void CreateTexture(int nWidth, int nHeight)
{
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC textureDesc;
    textureDesc.Width = nWidth;//Video width
    textureDesc.Height = nHeight;//Video height
    textureDesc.MipLevels = 1;
    textureDesc.ArraySize = 1;
    textureDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    textureDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    textureDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
    textureDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
    textureDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
    textureDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
    m_pD3dDevice->CreateTexture2D(&textureDesc, NULL, &m_pRGBATexture);

    D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC shaderResourceViewDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&shaderResourceViewDesc, 
               sizeof(D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC));
    shaderResourceViewDesc.Format = textureDesc.Format;
    shaderResourceViewDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
    shaderResourceViewDesc.Texture2D.MostDetailedMip = 0;
    shaderResourceViewDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = 1;
    m_pD3dDevice->CreateShaderResourceView(m_pRGBATexture, &shaderResourceViewDesc, &m_pRGBAShaderResouceView);

    ID3D11ShaderResourceView* pArrResources[] = {m_pRGBAShaderResouceView};
    m_pD3dDeviceContext->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &pArrShaderResourceView[0]);
}

void WriteVideoData(BYTE *pData, DWORD nSize)
{
    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE textureResource;
    ZeroMemory(&textureResource, sizeof(D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE));
    hr = m_pD3dDeviceContext->Map(m_pRGBATexture, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &textureResource);
    FAIL_RETURN_FALSE("Fail to map rgba texture resource.");
    BYTE *pMappedData = reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(textureResource.pData);
    BYTE *pTmpBuffer = pFrameBuffer;
    for (int i = 0; i < nHeight; ++i)
    {
        CopyMemory(pMappedData, pTmpBuffer, nWidth * 4);
        pMappedData += rgbaTextureResource.RowPitch;
        pTmpBuffer += nWidth * 4;
    }
    m_pD3dDeviceContext->Unmap(m_pRGBATexture, 0);
}
```

Here is how I create swap chain and set render target:

```
void InitSwapChain(int nWidth, int nHeight)//Displayed window size
{
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC swapChainDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&swapChainDesc, sizeof(DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC));
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Width = nWidth;
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Height = nHeight;
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;

    swapChainDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    swapChainDesc.BufferCount = 1;
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Scaling = DXGI_MODE_SCALING_STRETCHED;
    swapChainDesc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD;
    swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    swapChainDesc.OutputWindow = m_hWnd;
    swapChainDesc.Windowed = true;

    IDXGIDevice * dxgiDevice = NULL;
    hr = m_pD3dDevice->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIDevice), (void **)&dxgiDevice);
    FAIL_RETURN_FALSE("Fail to Query IDXGIDevice");

    IDXGIAdapter * dxgiAdapter = NULL;
    hr = dxgiDevice->GetParent(__uuidof(IDXGIAdapter), (void **)&dxgiAdapter);
    SAFE_RELEASE(dxgiDevice);
    FAIL_RETURN_FALSE("Fail to Query IDXGIAdapter");

    IDXGIFactory * dxgiFactory = NULL;
    hr = dxgiAdapter->GetParent(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory), (void **)&dxgiFactory);
    SAFE_RELEASE(dxgiAdapter);
    FAIL_RETURN_FALSE("Fail to Query IDXGIFactory");

    hr = dxgiFactory->CreateSwapChain(m_pD3dDevice, &swapChainDesc, &m_pSwapChain);
    FAIL_RETURN_FALSE("Fail to create swap chain");
    ID3D11Texture2D *pBackBuffer = NULL;
    m_pSwapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (LPVOID*)&pBackBuffer);
    hr = m_pD3dDevice->CreateRenderTargetView(pBackBuffer, NULL, &m_pBackBufferTargetView);
    m_pD3dDeviceContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &m_pBackBufferTargetView, m_pDepthStencilView);
}
```

I've set sample state for device context:

```
void SetSampleState()
{
    D3D11_SAMPLER_DESC samplerDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&samplerDesc, sizeof(D3D11_SAMPLER_DESC));

    samplerDesc.Filter = D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
    samplerDesc.AddressU = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
    samplerDesc.AddressV = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
    samplerDesc.AddressW = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
    samplerDesc.MipLODBias = 0.0f;
    samplerDesc.MaxAnisotropy = 16;
    samplerDesc.ComparisonFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;
    samplerDesc.BorderColor[0] = 0;
    samplerDesc.BorderColor[1] = 0;
    samplerDesc.BorderColor[2] = 0;
    samplerDesc.BorderColor[3] = 0;
    samplerDesc.MinLOD = 0;
    samplerDesc.MaxLOD = D3D11_FLOAT32_MAX;

    HRESULT hr = m_pD3dDevice->CreateSamplerState(&samplerDesc, &m_pSamplerState);
    FAIL_RETURN_FALSE("Fail to create sampler state");

    m_pD3dDeviceContext->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, &m_pSamplerState);
}
```

My pixel shader is very simple:

```
Texture2D shaderTexture;
SamplerState SampleType;

struct PixelInputType
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float4 blendingColor : COLOR;
    float2 tex : TEXCOORD0;
};

struct PiXelOutput
{
    float4 color : SV_TARGET;
};

PiXelOutput main(PixelInputType input)
{
    PiXelOutput output;
    float4 color = shaderTexture.Sample(SampleType, input.tex);
    output.color.x = color.z;
    output.color.y = color.y;
    output.color.z = color.x;
    output.color.w = 1.0;
    return output;
}
```

My problem is how to improve the render quality when the size of window displaying video is smaller than the size of video.At this time,  **shaderTexture.Sample** in pixel shader is the key point.But I have no idea how to get better sample result.I've trie to change parameter for sample state and it didn't work.I'm not familiar with DirectX.So did I miss something?
PS:I have tow pictures for contrast.
This one is d3d way:
[DirectX render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXVEc.png)
This one is gdi way and scaling image myself:
[gdi render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nD9Ms.png)
We can see that especially texts are fuzzy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you may want to look into is generating a mip chain for the texture in question, since your `D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR` filtering state (which is the best option for your usage) will leverage the mip levels of the texture.

The mip count should be along the lines of `1 + log2(max(width, height))`, but depending on the minimum display size you can use fewer mips. Then set the `textureDesc.MiscFlags` to include the `D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_GENERATE_MIPS` flag, and make sure the `BindFlags` member includes `D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE` and `D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET`. Then once you've filled the texture contents (after Unmap) you can call `ID3D11DeviceContext::GenerateMips()` on the immediate context.

Note that the binding and generate-mip flags won't work on a dynamic resource, so you'll need to keep your original, dynamic texture as-is, and add a second texture that's marked as `D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT` with the >1 mip levels and the other flags specified above. Then once you've finished filling the staging (dynamic) texture, call `ID3D11DeviceContext::CopyResource` to copy to the new texture. You'd make your shader resource view point to this new guy too.

This may help a little, but it still won't be as good as a really high-quality down-scale filter.

Comment: Thanks for response.I have set  'MipLevels'  to 0(other values I tried too) and flags as you said, but I got "E_INVALIDARG One or more arguments are invalid" when created the texture.Is there something wrong?

Comment: Create the device with the debug flag (D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG) and you should see the reason in the D3D debug output in your debugger.

Comment: And actually, looking at your code again, the issue is that the texture in question is being created as a dynamic resource (which makes sense since you're filling it from the CPU). Sadly you can't then use that as a render target resource, which is most likely why that's failing. I'll edit my answer with the correction :)

Comment: It works for me!And yes, it is still not as good as a really high-quality down-scale filter,but quite much better.I am trying to rewrite down-scale algorithm with HLSL in pixel shader to get better effect.Thanks all the same.